# is there a limit for the characters in text.erb?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I am learning rails and creating a `confirmation.text.erb` to send a text notification from my sample app. It looks like as follows:

```
Hi <%= @user_detail.outputs[0][0] %>, We noticed you havent paid your cable bill. you total remaining is <%= @user_detail.outputs[0][1] %>. You can pay bill online or visit the nearest cable center.
```

But when the text comes to my phone i only see `Hi <%= @user_detail.outputs[0][0] %>, We noticed you havent paid your abc bill. you total remaining` part. Why its not sending complete text?

UserMailer looks like below

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def payment_confirmation(user_detail)
    @user_detail = user_detail
    mail from: "no-reply@cerner.com", 
          to: '1112223333@messaging.sprintpcs.com', 
          subject: 'Payment notification'
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: what's the mailer method look like?

Comment: updated question with mailer method

Comment: now, what's `user_detail` look like? :)

Comment: #<Programmability::Response:0x007fe6d5897a38 @return_code=0, @outputs=[[Mike, 100.75]], @table=#<Programmability::Table:0x007fe6d5897a60 @rows=nil, @columns=["name", "total"]>>

Answer (score 0):

No, the character limitation you are experiencing is most likely the Email-SMS gateway you're using. Standard SMS is restricted to 160 characters, longer messages require using MMS but the gateway might just be truncating the message.

Comment: Thanks. is there any other way i can make this work?

Comment: @User7354632781 Google tells me that at least at one time there was a separate MMS gateway for Sprint, at `number@pm.sprint.com`. Since I am on another network I can't test this.